# how to optimize the performance of pandas retrieving stock quotes from yahoo feed

Tags: python, pandas

my code is about looping 1200+ nos of stock symbols and retrieve the historical quotes (160~200 days)from yahoo feed. as it takes time, i stored the quotes in csv, just make it to download the quotes for the time delta, i.e. any quotes for the date differences or any quote csv files are missing... i used the pandas function call get_data_yahoo(stocknum,start,end).

however, i found the time to take for the whole process make no difference, seems like d/l quotes for one day is same as that for 200 days... how did pandas handle the stock quotes from yahoo? any other feed better? any suggestion or enhancement i could make to speed up the process?

here below the function call i made for the stock quote retrieval.

def readStockPrice(stock,period=200,delay=1):

```
#define the period for stock filtering
now=dt.date.today()
end=now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
#start=(now-dt.timedelta(days=period)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

if os.path.isfile('cache/'+stock+'.csv'):
    df=pd.read_csv('cache/'+stock+'.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
    lastrecorddate=df.index.to_pydatetime()[-1].date()
    delta=(now-lastrecorddate).days
    if delta>delay:

        #print("retrieving "+stock+" quotes from the web")
        start=(lastrecorddate+dt.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        try:
            df_delta=web.get_data_yahoo(stock,start,end)
            df=df.append(df_delta)
            df_delta.to_csv('cache/'+stock+'.csv',header=False,mode='a')
        except IOError:
            return pd.DataFrame()
else:
    #print("retrieving "+stock+" quotes from the web")
    start=(now-dt.timedelta(days=period)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    try:
        df=web.get_data_yahoo(stock,start,end)
        if not df.empty:
            df.to_csv('cache/'+stock+'.csv')
    except IOError:
        return pd.DataFrame()

return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses _get_hist_yahoo to get your data in pandas/io/data.py, like below:

```
def _get_hist_yahoo(sym, start, end, retry_count, pause):
"""
Get historical data for the given name from yahoo.
Date format is datetime

Returns a DataFrame.
"""
start, end = _sanitize_dates(start, end)
url = (_HISTORICAL_YAHOO_URL + 's=%s' % sym +
       '&a=%s' % (start.month - 1) +
       '&b=%s' % start.day +
       '&c=%s' % start.year +
       '&d=%s' % (end.month - 1) +
       '&e=%s' % end.day +
       '&f=%s' % end.year +
       '&g=d' +
       '&ignore=.csv')
return _retry_read_url(url, retry_count, pause, 'Yahoo!')
```

I think it will be transferred from ulr into a SQL query like

```
where date between START_TIME and END_TIME
```

if Yahoo put index on date column, it could use index so response time isn't related with how long the period.

Comment: my code is to retrieve quotes from the stored csv (whole quotes for any one stock) or, download from yahoo. hence i need a time window, i.e. the period in nos of days, how far i go back from NOW. that why it is just concerned with start not end.

Comment: @timeislove sorry I misunderstand your question before, now I check source code of pandas and re-edit my answer, please see if it makes any help.

Comment: that's near what i am guessing... but even yahoo just put the parameters (index as u guess), the length of data chunk to download is vastly diff, i am talking a about 1:200 dataframe (there are 6~7 nos of column, e.g. open, high... adj close, etc.) time 1200+ nos of stocks!!! shouldn't there be any performance diff? and, if your guess is right, anything i could do to enhance the time to download (performance)?

Comment: or the overhead i retrieve the quotes from stored csv is even more than i download it from web?!!! my script is running by python3 under Lubuntu on SSD drive.

Comment: @timeislove how big is the data? I think query time isn't different because of index, but it's really strange after considering download time.

Comment: what's meaning of d/l quotes in your original article? time to call this function ?

Comment: d/l quotes means download stock quotes from yahoo... for one day, it is 6 nos of columns of dtype:float64 plus DatetimeIndex. the function to retrieve quotes from stored csv or from yahoo has already been fully shown in my original post.

Comment: what about try web.DataReader from this link pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html ? I think I am out of thought, maybe you reedit your question and make it focus on the download optimization part and see whether other people have good idea

Comment: tks.. i read somewhere that the DataReader function would actually call the get_data_yahoo for stock quotes... anyway, tks for your assistance.

Comment: i see same... strange, please tell me if you know why